# How can I ensure a correct assignment of ratings to reviews when a rating is missing (webscraping IMDB, python)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I adapted the code (see below) from an answer in stackoverflow ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376945/data-mining-imdb-reviews-only-extracting-the-first-25-reviews)) to also scrape the ratings on IMDB in addition to the review's title and content. 
 
Yet, when there is a review but no rating given, it messes up the assignment of the rating to the correct review. E.g., if review with index 3 has no rating, the next available rating (of another review) will be assigned to it. This leads to a wrong assignment of ratings (the index of the reviews and the ratings mismatches).

**How can I ensure a correct assignment of ratings to reviews?** 
E.g., a missing value is assigned to reviews that do not have a rating.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
url = (
    "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6320628/reviews/_ajax?ref_=undefined&paginationKey={}"
)
key = ""
data = {"title": [], "review": [], "rating": []}

while True:
    response = requests.get(url.format(key))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    # Find the pagination key
    pagination_key = soup.find("div", class_="load-more-data")
    if not pagination_key:
        break

    # Update the `key` variable in-order to scrape more reviews
    key = pagination_key["data-key"]
    for title, review, rating in zip(
        soup.find_all(class_="title"), soup.find_all(class_="text show-more__control"), soup.find_all(class_="rating-other-user-rating")
    ):
        data["title"].append(title.get_text(strip=True))
        data["review"].append(review.get_text())
        data["rating"].append(rating.get_text(strip=True))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example to check if there's a review rating or not. If not, the string `N/A` is used instead:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6320628/reviews/_ajax?ref_=undefined&paginationKey={}"
key = ""
data = {"title": [], "review": [], "rating": []}

while True:
    print(url.format(key))
    response = requests.get(url.format(key))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    # Find the pagination key
    pagination_key = soup.find("div", class_="load-more-data")
    if not pagination_key:
        break

    # Update the `key` variable in-order to scrape more reviews
    key = pagination_key["data-key"]

    for r in soup.select(".review-container"):
        title = r.find(class_="title")
        review = r.find(class_="text show-more__control")
        rating = r.find(class_="rating-other-user-rating")

        data["title"].append(title.get_text(strip=True))
        data["review"].append(review.get_text())
        data["rating"].append(rating.get_text(strip=True) if rating else "N/A")

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help me out! This resolved it perfectly.